# Portable Virtual Reality development toolkits - what are the differences?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, gear-vr, windows-mixed-reality, oculusgo

I'm exploring the possibilities for development in VR for a project I already did in UWP with C#. I don't expect to cut and paste it in Unity, don't worry, I'm fully aware it's much more complex than this. So I'm doing it in C# using Unity and would like to be able to port the application on the Gear VR/Occulus platform, Google Daydream as well as the Mixed Reality.

However, as I painfully found out numerous time, choosing the wrong development kit and realizing later that it's a dead-end is an enormous waste of time. But I can't seem to find a good explanation of the various libraries options (e.g. Mixed Reality Toolkit, OpenVR, Vuforia) that would allow me to chose a path.

Anobody could point me to a good technical document outlining the benefits and limits of each approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mixed Reality Toolkit` claims or at least has the goal in the future to support **all** platforms or at least the most common ones.

Ones like `Oculus`, `HoloLens/UWP`, `HTC Vive` etc will very probably be among them as they state on [MixedRealityToolkit-Unity](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity)

> Support a wide audience, allowing solutions to be built that will run on multiple VR / AR / XR platforms such as Mixed Reality, Steam/Open VR.

If this is fully the case already and if your specific target devices will be supported I can't tell. Until now you had/have to use a different SDK for each platform you want to use. But you can at least code your components more like interfaces and in a way that makes exchanging the SDK later easier.